# How to extract maths from latex documents

Tags: parsing, math, latex, pandoc

I'd like to be able to take a (potentially complex) LaTeX document and pull out the LaTeX source that would be rendered in `mathmode`. Options I can think of are,

- Grep for `equation`, `$$`, etc
- Use the `extract` package for LaTeX
- Use a converter like `pandoc` and extract the expressions from a simpler format
- Use the intermediate DOM from a renderer (`plasTeX` seems to be suited to this)

Unfortunately `grep`ing is hacky and doesn't work with macros; `extract` seems to work, but is awkward to use; both `pandoc` and `plasTeX` have trouble with complicated "real-world" documents.

Am I overlooking any easier/more robust way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

While pandoc cannot represent more complicated layouts, it does support math and the pandoc LaTeX reader detects math environments very reliably. So I'd suggest writing a [pandoc filter](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html) that drops everything but the [`Math` elements](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-types/blob/master/Text/Pandoc/Definition.hs#L261). You can also write filters in python, but in Haskell something along the lines of:

```
#!/usr/bin/env runhaskell
-- dropNonMath.hs
import Text.Pandoc.JSON

main = toJSONFilter dropNonMath
  where dropNonMath (Math x y) = Math x y
        dropNonMath _ = []
```

then run it with:

```
pandoc --filter dropNonMath.hs -f latex -t latex input.tex
```